# AWS API Gateway API Key not deploying properly via SAM deploy

Tags: api-key, gateway, sam

I have an API where I need some endpoints to require an API Key and others to not require the API Key. No matter what I do I cannot get the SAM deploy to properly configure the API Key required setting. I can get the API Key to be set for ALL endpoints but not selectively.

I have looked at this: https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/633
and I tried this: https://medium.com/@piyush.jaware_25441/how-to-configure-public-and-private-aws-apigw-paths-f2f201cd512

So far no luck. I really don't want to have to build separate apis for those that do and do not require the api key and I don't want to have to manually configure post deploy.

My setup:

I have template.yam that references and associated DefinitionBody in a separate file (and based on the first link that seems to be where part of the issue is but I have tried to circumvent by doing what second post suggests).

Template.yaml:

```
TestApi:
    Name: TestApi
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
      StageName: !Ref StageNameParameter
      Variables:
        Stage: !Ref StageNameParameter
      MethodSettings:
        - LoggingLevel:
            !FindInMap [AccountParameters, !Ref AccountType, ApiLoggingLevel]
          ResourcePath: "/*" 
          HttpMethod: "*" 
          DataTraceEnabled: !If [EnableAPIMonitoring, true, false] 
          MetricsEnabled: !If [EnableAPIMetrics, true, false] 
      Auth:
        #ApiKeyRequired: true # sets for all methods but commented out at the API level in this version
        Authorizers:
          AuthorizerFunction:
            :
          OktaAuthorizer:
            :
        DefaultAuthorizer: AuthorizerFunction
        ResourcePolicy:
          CustomStatements: [
            :
:
          ]
      DefinitionBody: #Use DefinitionBody as Swagger templates don't get transformed when using DefinitionUri
        Fn::Transform:
          Name: AWS::Include
          Parameters:
            Location: api-definition/api-1.0.10-swagger.yaml
    
PublicFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: lambdas/src/handlers/test/
      Handler: test.lambdaHandler
      Events:
        TestEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /test/me
            Method: get
            RestApiId: !Ref TestApi
            Auth:
              ApiKeyRequired: false
              Authorizer: OktaAuthorizer
      Policies:
        :
      
PrivateFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: lambdas/src/handlers/test/
      Handler: private.lambdaHandler
      Policies:
        :
      Events:
        PrivateEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /test/private
            Method: post
            RestApiId: !Ref TestApi
            Auth:
              ApiKeyRequired: true
              Authorizer: AuthorizerFunction
      

Open API spec:
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 1.0.9
  title: test-api
# x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source: "HEADER"
paths:
/test/me:
    get:
      summary: Test public
      operationId: TestEvent
      description: Public Test
      responses:
        200:
          $ref: "#/components/responses/OKFullResponse"
        400:
          $ref: "#/components/responses/BadRequest"
        404:
          $ref: "#/components/responses/NotFound"
        500:
          $ref: "#/components/responses/InternalServerError"
      security:
      - OktaAuthorizer: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: "params-only"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        httpMethod: "POST"
        uri: {"Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${PublicFunction.Arn}/invocations"}
        type: "aws_proxy"

/test/private:
    post:
      summary: test
      operationId: testPost
      description: Test
      parameters:
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/clientIdParam"
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/clientSecretParam"
      responses:
        200:
          $ref: "#/components/responses/OKLiteResponse"
        400:
          $ref: "#/components/responses/BadRequest"
        404:
          $ref: "#/components/responses/NotFound"
        500:
          $ref: "#/components/responses/InternalServerError"
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/BodyModel'
        description: Request body 
      security:
      - client_id: []
      - client_secret: []
      - AuthorizerFunction: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: "Validator"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        httpMethod: "POST"
        uri: {"Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${PrivateFunction.Arn}/invocations"}
        type: "aws_proxy"

components:
  securitySchemes:
    api_key:
      description: An API key ust accompany each request in the header
      type: apiKey
      name: x-api-key
      in: header
      x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source : HEADER
    client_id:
      :
    client_secret:
      :
    OktaAuthApiAuthorizer:
      :
    AccountApiAuthorizerFunction:
      :
```

I have tried a variety of things including

- setting the ApiKeyRequired only in the template
- configuring the api key only in the definition doc. Ex:

```
/test/private:
    post:
      summary: test
      operationId: testPost
      description: Test
      parameters:
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/clientIdParam"
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/clientSecretParam"
      responses:
        200:
          $ref: "#/components/responses/OKLiteResponse"
        400:
          $ref: "#/components/responses/BadRequest"
        404:
          $ref: "#/components/responses/NotFound"
        500:
          $ref: "#/components/responses/InternalServerError"
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/BodyModel'
        description: Request body 
      security:
      - api_key: []
      - client_id: []
      - client_secret: []
      - AuthorizerFunction: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: "Validator"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        httpMethod: "POST"
        uri: {"Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${PrivateFunction.Arn}/invocations"}
        type: "aws_proxy"
```

And I have tried various combinations of the above. Certainly there must be SOME way to configure this in either the definition or the template so that my deployment properly configures the API without me having to go in an manually re-configure. What am I missing??